# Downloading 12.04 Beta today - Does it now have the daily distro updates?

Tags: installation, 12.04

I downloaded the 12.04 Beta 2 on the day of launch and have been testing and sending bug reports.  I now want to install it on another machine.  My question is do I use the original image I downloaded and apply the daily distro updates through Update manager OR do a download a new image (because it now has the distro updates included).  To be clear I am asking does the 12.04 Beta 2 ISO get updated on a daily basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the daily live images: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/
They are generated daily.

Comment: Great, just what I was looking for.  I was prepared to do it as Ashu suggested but its makes life easier to download a current ISO

Answer (score 1):

No it does not get updated on a daily basis. Use the one u had downloaded previously and apply the update from updates manager.That should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "It doesn't really matter, to me".

<sub>sorry, I break into song sometimes</sub>

In all seriousness though, while the above answers are correct that you can just download the [daily ISO from here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/), it doesn't really matter. At this point in the game, it's not likely that you'll have a broken installer on a daily ISO, but it could happen in other parts of the development cycle.

Comment: Agreed, but Im on a learning curve and really want to understand the process 'during this distro upgrade and get more involved in the community in the future. Just crossing Ts and dotting i's

Comment: @StephenMyall No better way to learn than to just do it! That's how I learned everything I know now.